# set constraints in code

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I want to know if it is possible to set constraints in code, i have a piece off code from cocoa controls that crops a image, but it doesnt work when i rotate it to landscape, it shifts left, so i want to add constraints in the code, horizontally and verticaly to make it center in landscape view. The code i used is the [ykimagecropper](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/ykimagecropper)
Constraints or a other way to center the imageview in landscape.

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I've not done it myself but I know that creating constraint objects through code is indeed possible.

The iOS API documentation is here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/AppKit/Reference/NSLayoutConstraint_Class/NSLayoutConstraint/NSLayoutConstraint.html

There is also a iOS6 tutorial here that shows to setup NSLayoutConstraint objects.

http://ioscreator.com/auto-layout-in-ios-6-adding-constraints-through-code/